# Cannot start any app in XRDP

Tags: 21.10, xrdp

I installed XRDP under Ubuntu 21.10 and can log in log in successfully, as seen with the screenshot:

[image]

My problem is, apart from the "Settings" and "Advanced Network" I cannot start any application. Nothing happens. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering for example `top` shows the hour cursor and that's all. Terminal and the other shown programs cannot be started neither.

The user I am logged in and cannot start any program is the `Host default domain`. Does it change something? Is this a special user with some restrictions?

What am I doing wrong? Why is no app starting?

**UPDATE**:

As `root` I can start programs. This means the user I am logged in doesn't have some permissions. Any idea?

This is in the log file when I try to start any program:

```
some-user dbus-daemon[1191]: [session uid=1000 pid=1189] Activating service name='org.gnome.Terminal' requested by ':1.71' (uid=1000 pid=1703 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real ")
some-user org.gnome.Terminal[1707]: Non UTF-8 locale (ANSI_X3.4-1968) is not supported!
some-user dbus-daemon[1191]: [session uid=1000 pid=1189] Activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal' failed: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
some-user org.gnome.Terminal.desktop[1703]: # Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this forum is not really visited well, so I posted it as a job under upwork.com and in 15 minutes it was solved - for few bucks.

The guy who solved it told me there was a problem with `locale`. Maybe it helps somebody.

---

**Update according to the comment**
The freelancer told me the locale wasn't set and he created it and then it worked. That's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved the problem by creating the ~/.xsessionrc file explained in the link below

https://askubuntu.com/a/1233433