# Update to 22.04 - problem with Dock

Tags: dock, 22.04

I have updated to 22.04 on my desktop only to find that dock will not show in Desktop. It appears when hit the Activity button and it appears on the bottom....despite having set it as left hand side in Settings/appearance....I had Latte Dock installed before but have removed it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 20):

From a terminal:

`gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com`

Comment: This is quite a terse answer, can you expand a little?

Comment: Check out installing Latte Dock. That is where I got it from.

https://itsfoss.com/install-use-latte-dock-ubuntu/

Comment: To clarify: The command above has nothing to do with Latte Dock. It re-enables the usual  ubuntu dock if it was disabled. The article on Latte Dock simply happens to contain that command.

Comment: I have the same problem with gnome-desktop, after I played around with a different desktop trying to fix yet another problem. To see the launch dock I have to first press "Activities". However, the above solution does not work for me.

Comment: I had Dash to Dock installed in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Removed it from Gnome Extensions after the upgrade and then ran the command above. Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

From a terminal update the apt packages with:

```
sudo apt update
```

install the ubuntu-dock extension

```
sudo apt install -y gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

activate the ubuntu-dock extension

```
gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Same problem here, if enable the gnome-extension dock disappear!

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative..

GNOME 42 compatible alternative

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4703/dock-from-dash/

Comment: Nice extension, completely replaces buggy and unsupported Docky in Ubuntu 22!