# No option for appearance in settings after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04, settings, xdg

I upgraded from 21.10 and I wanted to tweak my appearance but that option itself is not present.

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem, and dock was not showing. At least I got it back using "gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com" as indicated here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403431/update-to-22-04-problem-with-dock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ued44y/2204_vanilla_gnome_no_appearance_setting_tab/)

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I am connecting to my server via xrdp.
This brings the Appearance menu item, but changing here the location of the dock doesn't actually have any effect.

Comment: Please expand. The answer as such is not clear, and the link may disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Actually when someone need to set `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` permanently:

```bash
echo 'export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME' >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

Log-out and log-in to the desktop session. As I understand correctly, when Wayland is in use we need to edit `~/.gnomerc` instead `~/.xsessionrc`. To apply system wide you may need to create new .desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.