# How to show the Appearance Editor?

Tags: appearance, favorites

I need to access the Appearance Editor in settings. This is missing in my Ubuntu 22.04.1 . So I found this webpage that recommends to set a variable:

[No option for appearance in settings after upgrade to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405331/no-option-for-appearance-in-settings-after-upgrade-to-22-04)

This is:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME gnome-control-center
```

As soon as I set this variable in Terminal a settings window opens, but I do not find the Appearance Editor there. How can I get to the Appearance Editor? Does it still exist in Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in 22.04.1: for me, the appearance tab becomes visible from within a Gnome session. It is not recommended to use that pane in a Gnome session because Ubuntu handles dark/light wallpapers differently than Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you vanadium for your answer. When I saw it I opened again the settings window by setting that variable again, and this time noticed the "<" icon in the upper left corner. Clicking on that got me to a settings window where the Appearance tab appeared in the left column. I had been in the Applications tab.