# Dock changed after i3 installation

Tags: dock, i3-wm

My dash on the left hand side of the desktop is suddenly at the bottom of the desktop after I installed the i3 window manager (`sudo apt install i3`) and logged in and out of an i3 session.

I tried:

- Changing the dash in Settings. The dash does not respond to any of the options (icon size, position, panel mode, etc.)
- Uninstalling and purging `i3` and all packages, that came with it (`sudo apt purge --autoremove "i3*"`)
- Logging in and out again, restarting
- `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`

How can I change the dash back to its old behavior and have it respond to settings?

(A Note: I also logged into a "Gnome Classic" session and had a look around. But I doubt that could be responsible for the changes or could it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently through me trying out window managers, all of `gnome-extensions` got somehow disabled. To re-enable it, I

- Opened gnome-exentions (typed "Extensions" in the dash)
- Enabled `Gnome Extensions` and especially the built-in extension `Ubuntu Dock`

The dock managed from the settings seems to be a gnome extension now. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403443/534953) led me on the right track.